# Adding C++ code to an iOS project

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to add a C++ library to an iOS project. I added the source code files to the project, but seems like they are not interpreted like a C++ code.

For instance, I get the following error in a header file:

```
namespace soundtouch // Unknown type name 'namespace'
{
```

I already tried to change the type in the File inspector to "C++ Source" and "C++ Header" - nothing changed.

How can I import a C++ library to an XCode project?

Comment: Are You uses .m or .mm files?

Comment: Used .m before. Changed to .mm - it worked!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++ source files must have a recognised extension; `.cpp`, `.cxx`, `.cc` etc. and they will be compiled as C++ files. You shouldn't need to change the file type manually if the extension is correct (and recognised) when you add the file. The compilation language is determined on a per-module basis.

Intermixing C++ and Objective-C is a different story. There's a whole section in the ADC documentation on Objective-C++ (which uses the `.mm` extension). So if you want to call C++ code from Objective-C, it will need to be done from a `.mm` module.

Given the error you quoted, it looks like you're probably trying to include a C++ header file in an Objective-C module. To make this work, you need to rename the Objective-C module to `.mm` and then the compiler will treat it as Objective-C++.

It takes a little planning to determine a clean boundary between the C++ and Objective-C code, but it is worth some up-front thinking.

This article is worth reading:

- [Mixing Objective-C, C++ and Objective-C++](http://philjordan.eu/article/mixing-objective-c-c++-and-objective-c++)

Answer (score 4):

Every Objective-C implementation file (`.m`) that directly, or indirectly, `#import`s any of the C++ header files must be changed to an Objective-C++ implementation file by changing its file extension to `.mm`.