# Getting error while using ObjC class include in .cpp file (unqualified-id @class)

Tags: ios, objective-c, wikitude-sdk

I am working with [Wikitude SDK](http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/ios/setupguideios.html) and while adding some file supported in Wikitude example folder its showing me Foundation file error like below.

> In file included from
> /Volumes/DATA/Dhanesh/Projects/experiments/AR/ARWikiDemo/ARWikiDemo/WikiSDK/Controller/Examples/Categories/PluginsAPI/CustomCamera/YUVFrameInputPlugin.cpp:11:
> In file included from
> /Volumes/DATA/Dhanesh/Projects/experiments/AR/ARWikiDemo/ARWikiDemo/WikiSDK/Controller/Examples/Categories/PluginsAPI/CustomCamera/WTDeviceCamera.h:9:
> In file included from
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:8:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:492:1:
> error: expected unqualified-id @class NSString, Protocol;

Not getting whats wrong here but it says that

All `NSString`, `NSObject`, `NSLog` are **unqualified-id @class**

I have set all related Linker flag and Header & Library search paths for that but still getting the above error.

Can anyone guide me on this whats going wrong here?

**Error Screenshot for reference:**

[image]

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Do you want to use Obj-C classes in the file? If so, change the file ending to `.mm` to use the Obj-C++ compiler.

Comment: Yes I have some classes with.cpp ext but strange thing is that the same .cpp ext working in Wikitude demo but while I want to create new demo its throwing above error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the Above issue, I struggle a lot, and finally, I am concluding this with the below solution.

- To use `.cpp` file in `ObjC` we required to convert that `.cpp` extension to `.mm` for `ObjC++` compiler only. (thanks Mats for your comment it's helped me a lot.)
- Compile the source as `ObjectiveC++` in the Build setting.

**Ref Link 1:** [Objective-C++ and .cpp files in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698459/objective-c-and-cpp-files-in-xcode/28073090#28073090)

**Ref Link 2:** [Adding C++ code to an iOS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138265/adding-c-code-to-an-ios-project)

Hope this will help others who are facing the same issue related to it.CPP ext.

Thanks.